# Dockerfile "RUN mkdir -p" не создает папку

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Мой Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN mkdir -p /var/test
COPY start.sh /var/
```

Запускаю билд командой:

```
sudo docker build --no-cache -t zabbix_test:latest .
```

стартую контейнер:

```
sudo docker run -it zabbix:latest
```

Захожу в папку /var и в ней нет ни файла "start.sh" ни папки "test"
Ткните пожалуйста носом, что я делаю не так?

Comment: zabbix_test != zabbix

Comment: Спасибо! был невнимателен((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в docker run используется название другого образа. Вы создаете образ под именем `zabbix_test`, а запускаете `zabbix`.

Т.е. вам необходимо запускать следующим образом: `sudo docker run -it zabbix_test:latest`